# MySQL: total number of rows which is scanned when using Explain

Tags: mysql

I want to know how to calculate the total number of rows which is scanned when using Explain in MySQL. I cannot find out any where mention about this officially.
There is an example I found out but I cannot understand why it uses multiplication for the UNION query.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post your explain query result, that will help both of us better

Answer (score -2):

You can just execute your query and then use a function like `mysql_num_rows($queryResource)` or any equivalent function from a DB-class (like PDO or mysqli) to determine the number of rows your `EXPLAIN` query returned.

For exameple (native, old PHP functions used, but you'll get the idea):

```
$rQuery = mysql_query('EXPLAIN SELECT table1.*, table2.some_field FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fk_table1id');
$iNumRows = mysql_num_rows($rQuery);
echo $iNumRows; # will output 2
```